# Node stream returns strings in strange formatting

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, formatting

I'm piping a node stream to stdout but it always writes it in strange manner, every line looks like an object, also as you can see the new line identifier is written.

```
stream.setEncoding('utf8');
stream.pipe(process.stdout, { end: true });
```

This is how the console log looks like. The output comes from creating a docker container using dockerode.

```
{"stream":"\n"}
{"stream":" ---\u003e Using cache\n"}
{"stream":" ---\u003e 7b0c642899ce\n"}
{"stream":"\n"}
{"stream":" ---\u003e Using cache\n"}
{"stream":" ---\u003e e01f16a7ed86\n"}
{"stream":"Step 8/11 : WORKDIR /home"}
```

Why is this the case and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by doing this instead of `stream.pipe(process.stdout)`

```
stream.on('data', data => {
  try {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data.toString()).stream);
  } catch (error) {
    return;
  }
});
```